# How do I make this definition symbol "... =[df] ..."?

Tags: latex-misc

I'm not sure what LaTeX command to use to generate a definition that looks like this:

Triangle = [df] a shape with three sides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this command (for math mode):

```
\newcommand\eqdef{\mathrel{{=}\textrm{\footnotesize[def]}}}
```

But a traditional `\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}` is just as fine:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would never use such a notation, personally; for text use words or punctuation:

> Triangle: a shape with three sides

Anyway, here's a possibility, with “df” not too big.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\eqdef}{%
  =\mathrel{%
     \vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle[\mathrm{df}]$}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Triangle${}\eqdef{}$a shape with three sides

\[
\log x \eqdef \int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}\,dt
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]